# Partition C disk running Windows 7 in half

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I am currently using Windows 7 64 bit on disk C and want to split it in half but not sure how to go about partitioning it.

I want it so that the C drive that is running Windows 7 gets sliced in two with a C partition and a D.

How can I do this? Is there a tool that I should use to help with the split?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: The solution i provided underneath, works for both 32 and 64 bit Windows7 (and Vista)

Comment: Unless you have really specific scenario requiring partitions I wouldn't recommend it performance wise.

Answer (score 11):

In Windows 7 you don't need any third party software to resize partitions anymore. You can do it right from the settings screen. This is included since windows vista.

To get to this utility, open up Control Panel, and type in "**partition**" into the search box you’ll immediately see the link show up:

[image: Create and format hard disk partitions]

In the **Disk Management screen**, just right-click on the partition that you want to shrink, and select “**Shrink Volume**” from the menu.

[image]

In the dialog you enter the amount you want to **shrink**, so **NOT the new size**, but how much you want to "slice off"

When this is all done, you have some new space left ! you can add this to an existing partition, or create a new one.

Comment: To get more available shrink space, a defragmentation could help

Answer (score 2):

This is a really easy to use, basic but FREE partition manager which supports Win7. Nice thing is, it has a nice little slider bar with grab handles just like PartitionMagic.

http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Comment: I can recommend this one. Works like a charm and feels just like Partion Magic when you're using it.