# Add a new partition to Windows

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd, restore, windows-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partition C disk running Windows 7 in half](https://superuser.com/questions/119105/partition-c-disk-running-windows-7-in-half)

I just got a new laptop with 750GB with Windows 7 pre-installed, office and some extra apps for the laptop.

The thing is I want to create add a new partition. How do I do it without erasing these apps?
I tried to boot from a System Image I created earlier but it doesnt have the option to partition..

Comment: some free software to resize a partition will do it. not sure which. the idea is resize the partition to make it smaller then you'll have room to create a new one.

Comment: I tried partition mgr and other partitioning software but it keeps failing, im gettitng "i/o error". Btw my system is booting on SSD

Comment: i've done it on spinning disk drives many times, used partition magic(not free).  You can't resize a partition that you are booting from. So you have to boot off another partition, or a CD or floppy disk or USB stick and run the partition program. Partition magic for example when I used it had "rescue disks"  which was a partition magic for DOS you could boot off a floppy. Probably some of the partition programs you've tried could boot off CD.

Comment: I just looked up about Partition manager  which you said you tried, as well as a free home edition, has a free bootable cd too, http://www.partitionwizard.com/download/pwhe7.iso   so you can boot off that. I have heard good things of gparted and partedmagic which is based on it.

Comment: will i be able to add partition during boot up?

Comment: after booting off the CD you are running the partition programming off the CD and yes you can add a partition, resize a partition on a hard drive in your computer that you didn't boot from. Then you can boot off the hard drive.

Answer (score 5):

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk Management.
Right-click on the volume you want to resize, click "Shrink," then create your new partition in the empty space generated.

Here are some screenshots of the process on [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) - they're Vista screenshots, but the process is the same in Windows 7.

As mentioned, you won't be able to resize the boot volume live, but you can always place the drive in a desktop or external enclosure temporarily.

You can do this from your Win7 installation disk as well. I'll defer to [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894.aspx) for the instructions as I'm not currently at a Win7 box to confirm.

Comment: I never tried that before. Will my files be safe by shrinking?

Comment: Easy in Vista and Windows 7 usually.  No special tools needed.

Comment: @mutu I can't answer that, really. Assuming there's absolutely nothing wrong with the HDD, if you do it in the GUI (Disk Management)? Yes, definitely. If you do it using the command prompt (`diskpart`)? Maybe. I've never lost data when resizing partitions in Vista/7, but there's a first time for everything. (edit: This sounds a little alarmist, but my point here really is 'If you absolutely can't afford to lose it, back it up.')

Comment: I try to do it but it will only allow me to shrink from 714GB to 340GB. I need 500GB at least

Comment: That's where the "unmovable files" mentioned in the links come in. I've never had much luck moving them (They can be things like the MFT or pagefile. Given that you've shrunk by half, I'd assume the MFT is the issue.) There are some further recommendations at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/working-around-windows-vistas-shrink-volume-inadequacy-problems/ , but I can't recommend any of them at this point unless you have a *good* backup.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

GParted is the best application that I tested, but it is for Linux. You can use it with a Linux Live CD.

If you resize or create a partitons, the softwares will be safe. But be careful — don't erase the partitons!